# Git as a team - subdomains or local envs?

Tags: git

I started using git some time ago. At the beginning I tried to work with it on my local env on windows, and I would push the changes to the dev server when ready. But I came across issues - the main one was that our local machines are so slow that the testing was really slowing development. To display the website after changes and refreshing the page was taking more than 20s !

So I moved on and created subdomains for each dev. There already was dev.mysite.com on the server. I added jer.mysite.com for me, dan.mysite.com for another dev, ext.mysite.com for external services working with us, and so on... Then cloned dev.mysite.com in every one of those. This works nice. Everyone got his own environnment on the server directly.

What I'm not very satisfied about, is the concept. Working like this could be a real problem if your team grows to include 20, 30 developers. Also, for merging, devs have issues not having a proper GUI (Vimdiff is really hard when you're not used to).

So, what would you guys recommend ?

Thanks ahead !

Comment: Why was it taking more than 20s to display the website locally?  Are better machines not an option, or is the issue beyond that?  What web server is it you are using, as that would probably help guide the answers a little better?  Can devs not merge on their own machines and then push to Git, before pulling down to their test area?

Comment: Your approach works great once you automate it: Setup your dns server with a wildcard domain, your web server to derive the document root from the subdomain given in the Host-header and a server-side git hook to checkout into an appropriately named directory (derived from the branch name). This can be easily extended to also request Let's encrypt certificates on the fly.

Comment: @gabe3886 We're using easyphp and everything works great... The codebase is just bad, and the machines are really slow and old (not made for devs really). What you suggest at the end of your comment if I'm right is to pull dev changes on their local machine, merge with their code, push that merged code to their own subdomain, test, and then commit a push to the dev ?

Comment: @Phillip thanks for your advices, we will think about it !

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to have decent dev environment for your team members and have them work with Git locally.

The money you save not upgrading their machines will probably be much less than paying your team for dealing with a remote dev environment.

Comment: I will suggest that to the boss :)